# Github Graphql API Single Commit single diff

Tags: github-api, github-graphql

I would like to find a way to get git diff on a single file on a single commit.
Now I can use this GitHub RESTful API to search a commit of all files diff.

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:sha
```

But now I would like to get a single file diff out of a commit. And I searched and found we cannot get a single file diff use GitHub API v3. So I was wondering is there any way we can use graphql API to fix this? Thanks!!